# no audio with asterisk 13 pjsip

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

I cannot playback any wav files from the dialplan or get any audio at all with asterisk 13 pjsip.  Server is not behind a nat, endpoints(clients) are.  Chan_sip works perfectly just not chan_pjsip
pjsip.ini:

It seems that the rtp is sending to the wrong ip address.
Got  RTP packet from    1.144.97.80:30880 
Sent RTP packet to      100.97.171.5:4002 
*UPDATE*
the GOT ip is the correct ip, the sent ip is incorrect.. how to fix?

```
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Try using TCP and enable notice in logger.conf. Also capture tcpdump and check on wireshark where any voice packets is being generated or not. How to Capture and Debug SIP Packets from asterisk using tcpdump and Wireshark :

tcpdump -w /tmp/capture-asterisk.pcap -p -n -s 0

Comment: This is not the correct forum for this question. Try the [asterisk-users](http://lists.digium.com/mailman/listinfo/asterisk-users) mailing list or #asterisk on freenode.

Comment: codecs fine. everything works well with chan_sip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to set rtp_symmetric=yes and force_rport=yes